# Generalized Courant-Fischer theorem

Tags: matrices, noncommutative-algebra, linear-algebra, reference-request

Consider some quaternionic matrix $A$.  A right eigvenvalue of $A$ is a quaternion $q$ such that $Ax=xq$ for some $x\in \mathbb{H}^n$.  Similarly, a left eigenvalue of $A$ is quaternion $q$ such that $Ax=qx$ for some $x\in \mathbb{H}^n$.

I am curious if there is a generalized version of the  [Courant-Fischer (min-max) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) for the right eigenvalues of Hermitian quaternionic matrices.  It is known that for a Hermitian quaternionic matrix the right eigenvalues are real.  This is the case I am most interested in.

For a good starting place in the references see: Fuzhen Zhang, Quaternions and matrices of quaternions, Linear Algebra Appl., 251 (1997), 21--57. MR 1421264 (97h:15020).

Comment: I found an interesting paper:

M. Seetharama Gowda and J. Tao, The Cauchy interlacing theorem in simple Euclidean Jordan algebras and some consequences.

Which can be found here:
http://www.math.umbc.edu/~gowda/tech-reports/trGOW08-02.pdf.

However I am looking for a form of the Courant-Fischer theorem in which we would take maxs/mins over vectors in H^n.